# How to use MongoDB/Nodejs with Express to retrieve save data for a JavaScript-based game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, phaser-framework

I'm trying to build a js browser game with Phaser and I've been learning Nodejs, Expressjs, and MongoDB along the way to serve it up. I'm new to Nodejs concepts like async and such. So far, I have my Node w/ Express server outputting an HTML file that calls up my game that's in a JS file. I've been able to communicate from my game to Nodejs using fetch and app.get calls to do things on Nodejs (e.g. send Twilio messages)

An example, just to make sure I'm getting the flow of this right:

in my static game.js~

```
function sendSMS() {
    var url = 'http://localhost:6000/index';

    fetch(url).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.text()); //just some confirmation message, outputs as a Promise
    }); 
}
```

And in my Node index.js~

```
app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
    var text = 'YOU FLUSHED THE TOILET'; \\for the game

    const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
    const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
    const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

    client.messages
    .create({
        body: text,
        from: process.env.FROM_NUMBER,
        to: process.env.TO_NUMBER
    })
    .then(message => console.log(message.sid))
    .done();
    res.send("USER HAS BEEN NOTIFIED THAT THEY FLUSHED THE TOILET");
})
```

My html webpage with the reference to game.js is served from my Node index.js when a user connects via this method:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'));
});
```

That works great, but in my testing I noticed I couldn't send data from my Node server to the js client file, as Nodejs is async.

I want to store saved user data in a Mongo DB to be loaded on every startup for each specific user. Preferably I'd get this data into game.js to be manipulated.

So my question is, how should I get data from MongoDB into my game.js? Or is there a design flow that I should switch to to make this better?

(Also let me know if my file naming schema is dumb and/or how to improve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i would highly recommend to watch some tutorials of NodeJS before you start.

I Really enjoyed this tutorial about nodejs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oXYLzuucwE&list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q

Now the statement "Nodejs is async" is to wide to describe how node works asynchronously. NodeJS interacts with the database in an asynchronous way. That is one of the biggest benefits of node. Especially when you scale to having 100,000 request every second and selecting from the database becomes your bottle neck.
By making that operation async your server can continue processing other requests and goes back on processing the previous request only when DB is done with selecting the data.

Beside that your server looks great it should pass index.html as root, but beside that no html pages need to be sent. Data should be passed in JSON format (although you can do it with other formats as XML or just passing strings) and should return httpResponse with the relevant data in the body.

Your client should  be the one responsible on making http requests to the server, using java script (jquery and ajax) in order to get that data.

One last thing your client side will have a lot of java script code that will generate the pages as your game grows. I will recommend using angular/ReactJS/VueJS as framework that will manage your client side.

It's a lot to swallow, at least it was for me at the beginning but there are alot of really good guides out there.